# cannot create connection to server '' at endpoint 'tcp://X.X.X.X:8531'

Tags: installation, arangodb

ArangoDB 3.3.4
architecture: 64bit
build-date: 2018-03-06 15:40:10
build-repository: tags/v3.3.4-0-g36841fe

**I started a 3 node Arangodb cluster using arangod. They are 192.168.19.171,192.168.19.172,192.168.19.181. Os is CentOS 7.2.
Command as below:**
192.168.19.181

```
#nohup arangod -c /etc/arangodb3/arangod.conf --database.directory /data1/agent/data --javascript.startup-directory /usr/share/arangodb3/js --javascript.app-path /data1/agent/apps --log.file /work/log/arangodb3/agent.log --log.force-direct false --agency.activate true --server.endpoint tcp://0.0.0.0:8531 --agency.my-address tcp://192.168.19.181:8531 --agency.size 3 --agency.supervision true --foxx.queues false --server.statistics true --agency.endpoint tcp://192.168.19.172:8531 --agency.endpoint tcp://192.168.19.171:8531&
#nohup arangod -c /etc/arangodb3/arangod.conf --database.directory /data1/dbserver/data --javascript.startup-directory /usr/share/arangodb3/js --javascript.app-path /data1/dbserver/apps --log.file /work/log/arangodb3/dbserver.log --log.force-direct false --server.endpoint tcp://0.0.0.0:8530 --cluster.my-address tcp://192.168.19.181:8530 --cluster.my-role PRIMARY --foxx.queues false --server.statistics true --cluster.agency-endpoint tcp://192.168.19.181:8531 --cluster.agency-endpoint tcp://192.168.19.172:8531 --cluster.agency-endpoint tcp://192.168.19.171:8531&
#nohup arangod -c /etc/arangodb3/arangod.conf --database.directory /data1/coordinator/data --javascript.startup-directory /usr/share/arangodb3/js --javascript.app-path /data1/coordinator/apps --log.file /work/log/arangodb3/coordinator.log --log.force-direct false --server.endpoint tcp://0.0.0.0:8529 --cluster.my-address tcp://192.168.19.181:8529 -cluster.my-role COORDINATOR --foxx.queues true --server.statistics true --cluster.agency-endpoint tcp://192.168.19.181:8531 --cluster.agency-endpoint tcp://192.168.19.172:8531 --cluster.agency-endpoint tcp://192.168.19.171:8531&
```

192.168.19.171

```
#nohup arangod -c /etc/arangodb3/arangod.conf --database.directory /data1/agent/data --javascript.startup-directory /usr/share/arangodb3/js --javascript.app-path /data1/agent/apps --log.file /work/log/arangodb3/agent.log --log.force-direct false --agency.activate true --server.endpoint tcp://0.0.0.0:8531 --agency.my-address tcp://192.168.19.171:8531 --agency.size 3 --agency.supervision true --foxx.queues false --server.statistics true --agency.endpoint tcp://192.168.19.181:8531 --agency.endpoint tcp://192.168.19.172:8531&
#nohup arangod -c /etc/arangodb3/arangod.conf --database.directory /data1/dbserver/data --javascript.startup-directory /usr/share/arangodb3/js --javascript.app-path /data1/dbserver/apps --log.file /work/log/arangodb3/dbserver.log --log.force-direct false --server.endpoint tcp://0.0.0.0:8530 --cluster.my-address tcp://192.168.19.171:8530 --cluster.my-role PRIMARY --foxx.queues false --server.statistics true --cluster.agency-endpoint tcp://192.168.19.181:8531 --cluster.agency-endpoint tcp://192.168.19.172:8531 --cluster.agency-endpoint tcp://192.168.19.171:8531&
#nohup arangod -c /etc/arangodb3/arangod.conf --database.directory /data1/coordinator/data --javascript.startup-directory /usr/share/arangodb3/js --javascript.app-path /data1/coordinator/apps --log.file /work/log/arangodb3/coordinator.log --log.force-direct false --server.endpoint tcp://0.0.0.0:8529 --cluster.my-address tcp://192.168.19.171:8529 --cluster.my-role COORDINATOR --foxx.queues true --server.statistics true --cluster.agency-endpoint tcp://192.168.19.181:8531 --cluster.agency-endpoint tcp://192.168.19.172:8531 --cluster.agency-endpoint tcp://192.168.19.171:8531&
```

192.168.19.172

```
#nohup arangod -c /etc/arangodb3/arangod.conf --database.directory /data1/agent/data --javascript.startup-directory /usr/share/arangodb3/js --javascript.app-path /data1/agent/apps --log.file /work/log/arangodb3/agent.log --log.force-direct false --agency.activate true --server.endpoint tcp://0.0.0.0:8531 --agency.my-address tcp://192.168.19.172:8531 --agency.size 3 --agency.supervision true --foxx.queues false --server.statistics true --agency.endpoint tcp://192.168.19.181:8531 --#agency.endpoint tcp://192.168.19.171:8531&
#nohup arangod -c /etc/arangodb3/arangod.conf --database.directory /data1/dbserver/data --javascript.startup-directory /usr/share/arangodb3/js --javascript.app-path /data1/dbserver/apps --log.file /work/log/arangodb3/dbserver.log --log.force-direct false --server.endpoint tcp://0.0.0.0:8530 --cluster.my-address tcp://192.168.19.172:8530 --cluster.my-role PRIMARY --foxx.queues false --cluster.agency-endpoint tcp://192.168.19.181:8531 --cluster.agency-endpoint tcp://192.168.19.172:8531 --cluster.agency-endpoint tcp://192.168.19.171:8531&
#nohup arangod -c /etc/arangodb3/arangod.conf --database.directory /data1/coordinator/data --javascript.startup-directory /usr/share/arangodb3/js --javascript.app-path /data1/coordinator/apps --log.file /work/log/arangodb3/coordinator.log --log.force-direct false --server.endpoint tcp://0.0.0.0:8529 --cluster.my-address tcp://192.168.19.172:8529 --cluster.my-role COORDINATOR --foxx.queues true --server.statistics true --cluster.agency-endpoint tcp://192.168.19.181:8531 --cluster.agency-endpoint tcp://192.168.19.172:8531 --cluster.agency-endpoint tcp://192.168.19.171:8531&
```

**there always have some connection error, and the cluster not started!!!! For example, on 192.168.19.181**

```
#tail -2 /work/log/arangodb3/agent.log
INFO {cluster} cannot create connection to server '' at endpoint 'tcp://192.168.19.172:8531'
INFO {cluster} cannot create connection to server '' at endpoint 'tcp://192.168.19.171:8531'

#tail -2 work/log/arangodb3/coordinator.log
INFO {agencycomm} Flaky agency communication to http+tcp://192.168.19.181:8531. Unsuccessful consecutive tries: 45 (71.27s). Network checks advised.
INFO {agencycomm} Flaky agency communication to http+tcp://192.168.19.172:8531. Unsuccessful consecutive tries: 40 (48.65s). Network checks advised.

#tail -2 /work/log/arangodb3/dbserver.log
INFO {agencycomm} Flaky agency communication to http+tcp://192.168.19.172:8531. Unsuccessful consecutive tries: 45 (71.27s). Network checks advised.
INFO {agencycomm} Flaky agency communication to http+tcp://192.168.19.171:8531. Unsuccessful consecutive tries: 46 (76.47s). Network checks advised.
```

but I confirmed the endpoint, it is LISTEN,

```
[root@192.168.19.181 data1]# netstat -an|grep 8531
tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:8531 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN
tcp 0 0 192.168.19.181:40763 192.168.19.181:8531 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 192.168.19.181:8531 192.168.32.32:56349 ESTABLISHED
tcp 0 0 192.168.19.181:8531 192.168.32.32:56350 ESTABLISHED
tcp 0 0 192.168.19.181:8531 192.168.19.171:36376 ESTABLISHED
tcp 0 0 192.168.19.181:8531 192.168.19.172:60199 ESTABLISHED
tcp 0 0 192.168.19.181:40804 192.168.19.181:8531 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 192.168.19.181:40792 192.168.19.181:8531 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 192.168.19.181:40777 192.168.19.181:8531 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 192.168.19.181:40778 192.168.19.181:8531 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 192.168.19.181:8531 192.168.32.32:56351 ESTABLISHED
tcp 0 0 192.168.19.181:40789 192.168.19.181:8531 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 192.168.19.181:40764 192.168.19.181:8531 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 192.168.19.181:40803 192.168.19.181:8531 TIME_WAIT

[root@192.168.19.171 data1]# netstat -an|grep 8531
tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:8531 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN
tcp 0 0 192.168.19.171:45847 192.168.19.171:8531 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 192.168.19.171:45918 192.168.19.171:8531 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 192.168.19.171:38987 192.168.19.181:8531 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 192.168.19.171:38976 192.168.19.181:8531 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 192.168.19.171:45842 192.168.19.171:8531 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 192.168.19.171:45848 192.168.19.171:8531 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 192.168.19.171:45857 192.168.19.171:8531 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 192.168.19.171:36376 192.168.19.181:8531 ESTABLISHED
tcp 0 0 192.168.19.171:45889 192.168.19.171:8531 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 192.168.19.171:45885 192.168.19.171:8531 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 192.168.19.171:39014 192.168.19.181:8531 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 192.168.19.171:45860 192.168.19.171:8531 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 192.168.19.171:45866 192.168.19.171:8531 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 192.168.19.171:38983 192.168.19.181:8531 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 192.168.19.171:38949 192.168.19.181:8531 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 192.168.19.171:45895 192.168.19.171:8531 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 192.168.19.171:38942 192.168.19.181:8531 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 192.168.19.171:39009 192.168.19.181:8531 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 192.168.19.171:38953 192.168.19.181:8531 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 192.168.19.171:45904 192.168.19.171:8531 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 192.168.19.171:38995 192.168.19.181:8531 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 192.168.19.171:45916 192.168.19.171:8531 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 192.168.19.171:45871 192.168.19.171:8531 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 192.168.19.171:38962 192.168.19.181:8531 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 192.168.19.171:45901 192.168.19.171:8531 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 192.168.19.171:39001 192.168.19.181:8531 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 192.168.19.171:39031 192.168.19.181:8531 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 192.168.19.171:45836 192.168.19.171:8531 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 192.168.19.171:38999 192.168.19.181:8531 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 192.168.19.171:39028 192.168.19.181:8531 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 192.168.19.171:38968 192.168.19.181:8531 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 192.168.19.171:45839 192.168.19.171:8531 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 192.168.19.171:45832 192.168.19.171:8531 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 192.168.19.171:38958 192.168.19.181:8531 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 192.168.19.171:38970 192.168.19.181:8531 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 192.168.19.171:38946 192.168.19.181:8531 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 192.168.19.171:38982 192.168.19.181:8531 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 192.168.19.171:45870 192.168.19.171:8531 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 192.168.19.171:45877 192.168.19.171:8531 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 192.168.19.171:39018 192.168.19.181:8531 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 192.168.19.171:45881 192.168.19.171:8531 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 192.168.19.171:38940 192.168.19.181:8531 TIME_WAIT

[root@192.168.19.172 data1]# netstat -an|grep 8531
tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:8531 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN
tcp 0 0 192.168.19.172:34810 192.168.19.181:8531 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 192.168.19.172:34821 192.168.19.181:8531 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 192.168.19.172:42547 192.168.19.172:8531 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 192.168.19.172:42528 192.168.19.172:8531 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 192.168.19.172:42521 192.168.19.172:8531 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 192.168.19.172:42475 192.168.19.172:8531 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 192.168.19.172:42486 192.168.19.172:8531 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 192.168.19.172:34842 192.168.19.181:8531 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 192.168.19.172:60199 192.168.19.181:8531 ESTABLISHED
tcp 0 0 192.168.19.172:34862 192.168.19.181:8531 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 192.168.19.172:34854 192.168.19.181:8531 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 192.168.19.172:42536 192.168.19.172:8531 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 192.168.19.172:42513 192.168.19.172:8531 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 192.168.19.172:42498 192.168.19.172:8531 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 192.168.19.172:34815 192.168.19.181:8531 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 192.168.19.172:42485 192.168.19.172:8531 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 192.168.19.172:34831 192.168.19.181:8531 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 192.168.19.172:42497 192.168.19.172:8531 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 192.168.19.172:42550 192.168.19.172:8531 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 192.168.19.172:34878 192.168.19.181:8531 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 192.168.19.172:34867 192.168.19.181:8531 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 192.168.19.172:34822 192.168.19.181:8531 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 192.168.19.172:34846 192.168.19.181:8531 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 192.168.19.172:42509 192.168.19.172:8531 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 192.168.19.172:42479 192.168.19.172:8531 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 192.168.19.172:34832 192.168.19.181:8531 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 192.168.19.172:34884 192.168.19.181:8531 TIME_WAIT
```

**So, why the connection problem occured and how to fixed? Thanks !!**

Comment: just because it listens, it doesn't mean that the servers can communicate. try reaching the individual ports via http from each machine.

Comment: Please use `curl` to access the services on the other machines. If you cannot reach any other service, you have network issues to solve first. Can they ping each other? What does `iptables -L` say on each machine? Etc

Comment: my bad. one server' iptables  service is enabled. Thanks.

Comment: Cool. These are embarrassing ones and the most experienced people fall for it.

Answer (score 0):

Please use generic tools to check whether communication endpoints are reacheable by each others.

- [Netcat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat) can be used to inspect whether you're able to establish specific TCP-Connections. Non-SSL protocols can be hand typed to verify the application.
- [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/) to perform complete HTTP requests
- [ngrep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ngrep) or [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to check aspects of the TCP protocol to see why curl or netcat aren't able to communicate
- [iptables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iptables) to validate filter rules configured on your machine.

(as in the end the original Asker found out that connections were blocked)